# Why does Faker return the same name when used in a multiprocessing pool in WSL2?

Tags: python, wsl-2

I am using Faker 14.2.0 to generate names in a Python 3.9.2 `multiprocessing.Pool`, but I don't get a unique name every time.

```
import multiprocessing

from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

def print_name(index):
    lock.acquire()
    print(index, fake.name())
    lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        for i in range(10):
            pool.apply_async(print_name, args=(i, ))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

The output shows the unique index, but mostly duplicate names:

```
0 Jacob Hughes
5 Jacob Hughes
2 Jacob Hughes
3 Jacob Hughes
4 Jacob Hughes
1 Jacob Hughes
6 Jacob Hughes
8 Kristi Herrera
7 Jacob Hughes
9 Kristi Herrera
```

The expected behavior in the REPL:

```
>>> from faker import Faker
>>> fake = Faker()
>>> fake.name()
'Christian Simpson'
>>> fake.name()
'Timothy Singh'
>>> fake.name()
'Michael Fletcher'
```

If this is a synchronization problem, shouldn't the `Lock` solve that?

**Edit**: thas is happening in Windows Subsystem for Linux 2, with both Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) and Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS.

Comment: If it helps: I cannot reproduce the issue using python 3.9.12 and faker 14.2.0 on my machine (win 10). The produced indices are always in order and the names always unique. Removing the lock-feature from the code does not change the behaviour.

Comment: @christian-karcher I should've originally mentioned this is happening under WSL2 with Debian and Ubuntu, and have edited the question accordingly. After reading your comment, I tested it with VS2022 (win 11) and got the same results you describe - indices in order, unique names. Weird.